# What is this plant with tendrils that exhibits guttation?

Tags: identification

[image: see the gutation droplets?]

[image]

I thought that it was a busy lizzie until i saw the tendril... my other busy lizzie doesn't have that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Its definitely not a busy lizzie - it's obviously a tendril climbing plant, but I'm not sure precisely what it is - similar to Mandevilla, but the leaves on yours look a little too soft and thin to be that. Whatever it is, those tendrils are looking for something thin and vertical to wrap round so it can climb up...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly a passion fruit *Passiflora edulis* where the leaves are young and not yet forming a deeply cleft shape. Watch as the later leaves emerge and see if they become still a single leaf but with 3 lobes. Lots of images on Google of passion fruit leaves.

Comment: I totally agree. My Passiflora edulis plants are grown from seed and the young basal leaves look exactly like this.

Comment: Ah! Now I recall, I have indeed sowed some of the passionfruit seeds from the fruit few months back! Thanks a lot!