# What is the name of this vine?

Tags: identification

I had this plant growing in my greenhouse. I brought a couple of plants in over winter and now new leaves have emerged so that I am puzzled about what this is. Do you know its name?

[image]

Comment: Damien, please tell us more.  Definitely need more information.  You really should NOT  allow strange plants, smokers anything purchased from stores or given by friends into your green house.  What have you been growing?  This plant is a trilobed plant of some kind.  More pics of your green house and perhaps your suspicions...

Comment: I have to disagree @stormy, this is a *Passiflora* of some kind and I cannot think of a reason why you wouldn't want one (aside from obvious disease which is not evident in this image). They are incredible plants.

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades what the heck are you disagreeing about?  What I said about greenhouses is correct sweetheart. Basic warning...my goodness have you got a...grins.

Comment: Thanks for the info . My greenhouse​ is happy and very healthy @stormy. I've grown many plant to what i didn't know what they are and never had any issues. I wasn't asking to what i should and shouldn't be doing / allowing in my greenhouse so that bit of advisement was not needed. Thanks for the possible identification

Comment: I wasn't ID ing your plant...I always go to the precursors first.  Truly a super plant.  Your comment about bringing in plants that you did not know triggered my knee reflex action about green houses...just to amplify a tried and true rule...I am glad your greenhouse is happy and that you are a more than intermediate gardener even a master gardener.  I quit worrying about knowing other's qualifications and just BLURT.  Sorry, did not mean to offend you!  I was just asking questions that would help me help you.  Do be careful allowing strange plants and soil into your greenhouse esp. smokers!

Answer (score 10):

I think this is [Passiflora edulis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passiflora_edulis), a vine that has whole basal leaves followed by somewhat lobed leaves and then trilobed leaves. It also has tendrils and exhibits gutattion.
See [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31227/what-is-this-plant-with-tendrils-that-exhibits-guttation) for different pictures of it.

Comment: Probably right about *Passiflora* not 100% sure about *P. edulis* though. The leaves look exceptionally glossy, almost to the extent of *Prunus laurocerasus* and *P. edulils* tends to more regularly trilobate.

Comment: That said, *P. edulis* is more common than other candidates (and of course could have been grown from the seeds of shop bought fruit), so applying Occam's razor, gives *P. edulis* as the answer.